# Get recall (sensitivity) and precision (PPV) values of a multi-class problem in PyML

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm, pyml

I am using [PyML](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/) for SVM classification. However, I noticed that when I evaluate a multi-class classifier using LOO, the results object does not report the sensitivity and PPV values. Instead they are 0.0:

```
from PyML import *
from PyML.classifiers import multi

mc = multi.OneAgainstRest(SVM())
data = VectorDataSet('iris.data', labelsColumn=-1)
result = mc.loo(data)

result.getSuccessRate()
>>> 0.95333333333333337
result.getPPV()
>>> 0.0
result.getSensitivity()
>>> 0.0
```

I have looked at the code but couldn't figure out what is going wrong here. Has somebody a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get the usual Precision/Recall measurements on a multi-class problem. You have to get Precision/Recall for each class, and you can compute a weighted average.

I don't know about the specifics of PyML, but you can just go through the predictions and calculate them for each class.

Answer (score 2):

For multiclass sensitivity calculation, you can use [scikit-learn metrics API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score).

> Notice `average=None` for sensitivity of each class independently.

```
sklearn.metrics.recall_score(Y_true,Y_prediction,average=None)
```

For instance, if `Y` has 4 classes, the result will be an array with the sensitivity of each one.

```
array([0.96629213, 0.86263736, 0.81920904, 0.7704918])
```