# How to plot precision and recall of a CNN in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How to plot the precision and recall curves of a CNN?
I have generated the scores from CNN and want to plot the precision-recall curve, but I am unable to get that.
I have calculated `TP`, `TN`, `FP`, and `FN` using:

```
idx = (ACTUAL()==1);
p = length(ACTUAL(idx));  
n = length(ACTUAL(~idx));   
N = p+n;
tp = sum(ACTUAL(idx)==PREDICTED(idx));   
tn = sum(ACTUAL(~idx)==PREDICTED(~idx));   
fp = n-tn;   
fn = p-tp;
```

The formula of precision and recall is

```
precision = tp/(tp+fp)
```

but with that, I am getting some undesired plot.

I have obtained scores of the CNN using the following command:

```
[YTest,score]=classify(convnet,TestData)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB has a function for creating ROC curves and similar performance curves (such as precision-recall curves) in the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox: [`perfcurve`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html).
By default, the ROC curve is calculated.
The function has the following syntax:

```
[X, Y] = perfcurve(labels, scores, posclass)
```

Here, `labels` is the true label for each sample, `scores` is the prediction of the CNN (or any other classifier), and `posclass` is the label of the class you assume to be "positive" - which appears to be `1` in your example. The outputs of the `perfcurve` function are the `(x, y)` coordinates of the ROC curve, so you can easily plot it using

```
plot(X, Y)
```

To make `perfcurve` plot the precision-recall curve instead of the ROC curve, you have to set the optional [`'XCrit'`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html#bunsogv-XCrit) and [`'YCrit'`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html#bunsogv-YCrit) arguments of the function. As described in the documentation, different pre-defined criteria such as number of false positives (`'fp'`), true positive rate (`'tpr'`), accuracy (`'accu'`) and many more, or even custom functions can be used.

By setting `'XCrit'` to `'tpr'` (Recall) and `'YCrit'` to `'prec'` (Precision), a precision-recall curve is created:

```
[X, Y] = perfcurve(labels, scores, posclass, 'XCrit', 'tpr', 'YCrit', 'prec');
plot(X, Y);
xlabel('Recall')
ylabel('Precision')
xlim([0, 1])
ylim([0, 1])
```

For example (using randomly generated data and a SVM):

[image: Sample precision recall curve]

Comment: the predicted score of CNN is 1000*100 in size(100 classes and 10 sample from each class). so when trying to use perfcurve it is giving error " You must pass scores as a vector of floating-point values.
 " 
what I have done is done column-wise sum to create a score vector. am I doing it right or wrong? if wrong then please suggest me the suitable way.

Comment: You can only evaluate the precision and recall for binary classification. I would usually recommend plotting one curve for each class. For that, you would insert `score(:,k)` into `perfcurve`. If you need to aggregate them into one plot, there are multiple ways to, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420025/4221706). The simplest way would be to create the plots for each class as shown above and average them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **hbaderts** is correct but the end of the answer is wrong.

```
[X,Y] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass,'xCrit', 'fpr', 'yCrit', 'tpr');
```

Then the generated Receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve is correct.
[image]

Comment: There is no threshold value in perfcurve.

Comment: [X,Y,Thres,AUC] = perfcurve(labels,scores,true); Is "Thres" is not the threshold value?